# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' when labeling column

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, stock, labeling

I am trying to compare values in a column and replace them with Up/Down.
basically, labelling the data frame.

this is the code I am using.

```
dataset['UpDown'] = dataset['Return_Out']
dataset.UpDown[dataset.UpDown < 0] = 'Down'
dataset.UpDown[dataset.UpDown >= 0] = 'Up'
```

The 'Down' part works perfectly. And after that, the numbers in the column are getting converted to 9090999..-e format and I am getting the following error during 'Up' line.

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

[Screenshot before labeling the Down part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNksd.png)

[partial output image after adding 'Down'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxPeS.png)

[Sample dataset screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doaW1.png)

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: added. Thank you so much for the prompt reply @AkshayNevrekar
New to labeling datasets. No idea why it is bouncing like that after partially labeling. :/

Comment: Won't `dataset.UpDown[dataset.UpDown < 0] = 'Down'` it so that `dataset.UpDown` becomes `'down'`? Meaning, you're replacing `dataset.UpDown` with a string. (No clue how pandas inner magic works)

Comment: Better use `np.where` here. `np.where(dataset['UpDown'] < 0, 'Down','Up')` . If it gives same error then I think `dataset.UpDown` contains `str`

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar,  np.where(dataset.UpDown[dataset.UpDown] >= 0, 'Up', 'Down')
it doesnt throw error nor replace it with 'Down' or 'Up'. it is simply going to the next statement.

Comment: @Torxed, yes, I think so too. Struck here solving this for a couple of hours now

Comment: Woah! How could I do such a silly mistake. Thanks soo soo much @AkshayNevrekar

Comment: `dataset['UpDown'] = np.where(dataset['UpDown <0 '], 'Down','Up') ` and `dataset['UpDown'] = np.where(dataset['UpDown'] < 0, 'Down','Up')` What would be the difference?

Comment: The first expression checks for column with name `UpDown <0 ` which is not there in your dataframe while 2nd one checks for values in that column

Comment: Thank you so much again. @AkshayNevrekar.

Answer (score 2):

The first line works ok because, at that point, `dataset.UpDown` is likely `int`-like (specifically, probably an `int64` dtype if I had to guess). So the comparison to `0` works fine.  But the line

```
dataset.UpDown[dataset.UpDown < 0] = 'Down'
```

will also make some elements of that column `str` and make the column dtype `object`.

When you go to do the second comparison, Pandas doesn't like that you're comparing the `str` ('Down') elements to an integer.  (`0 >= 'x'` is technically OK in pure Python, but not allowed by Pandas.)

Instead, you can replace both lines with just:

```
dataset['UpDown'] = np.where(dataset.UpDown < 0, 'Down', 'Up')
```